# how to use looping and array with php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, logic, pseudocode

I am newbie in programming php, i have output query data from database like this

```
name    activity  payment
english  activ A   20
english  activ B   25
english  activ c   30
biology  activ d   50
biology  activ e   60
```

but i want to show output like this:

```
name    activity  payment
english  activ A   20
         activ B   25
         activ c   30
biology  activ d   50
         activ e   60
```

how logic program use PHP to show only one name in the same name?

can you solve this problem?

Comment: Where is the code you have tried?

Comment: When looping through the code, save the current row's `name` in a variable, e.g. `$name_old` and compare it with the next row's `name` in the loop's following iteration. If they are similar, the script should output an empty cell.

Comment: Why don't you use `group by` along with `group_concat`

Comment: @Kristian can you show me complate code your version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

database will show names same as

```
name    activity  payment
english  activ A   20
english  activ B   25
english  activ c   30
biology  activ d   50
biology  activ e   60
```

but if you want to show records as

```
name    activity  payment
english  activ A   20
         activ B   25
         activ c   30
biology  activ d   50
         activ e   60
```

you can do this in php

for example

```
$datas = $fetched_data; // $fetched_data store all data which is selected          from database
// now in php use foreach loop
$previous_colm = "";
foreach($datas as $data){
    if($previous_colm == $data['name']){
          // echo without printing column name again
          echo $data['activity']." ".$data['payment'];
    }else{
         // echo with new column name
         echo echo $data['name']." ".$data['activity']." ".$data['payment'];
    }
    $previous_colm = $data['name'];
}
```

now this will output same as you want...!!!

Comment: thanks its help me a lot. but i have question why in $previous_colm=" " is empty?

Comment: $previous_colm is empty because i added this condition 
 if($previous_colm == $data['name']){
// then print data without repeating name 

so first time $previous_colm is empty that means condition is false so print the user data atleast one then second time loop 

setting $previous_colm = $data['name'];
so condition will be true so name will no repeat anymore

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array(
    array('name' => 'english', 'activity' => 'activ A', 'payment' => 20),
    array('name' => 'english', 'activity' => 'activ B', 'payment' => 25),
    array('name' => 'english', 'activity' => 'activ c', 'payment' => 30),
    array('name' => 'biology', 'activity' => 'activ d', 'payment' => 50),
    array('name' => 'biology', 'activity' => 'activ e', 'payment' => 60),
);

$different_names = get_different_names($arr);
echo "Name Activity Payment";
display($different_names, $arr);



function display($different_names, $arr) {
    foreach($different_names as $name) {
        foreach($arr as $row) {
            if($row['name'] == $name)
                echo "</br> {$row['name']}  {$row['activity']} {$row['payment']} ";
        }
    }
}

function get_different_names($arr) {
    $different_names = array();
    foreach($arr as $row) {
        if(!in_array($row['name'], $different_names))
            $different_names[] = $row['name'];
    }
    return $different_names;
}
```

p.s.
Zebi Rajpot `s solution is good. But I dont think it will produce the desired output if the result is not sorted by *name*.